# vectorize upper level of a vectoized code - python - numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

essentially I'd like to vectorize the `for` loop below, the `np.apply_along_axis` was used to speed the comparison. but I'd like to use eliminate also the other `for` loop. any chance of doing that? the final objective is indeed a mask to be used all at once (inside the loop, it's what I am doing).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

original = pd.DataFrame(
    [np.arange(0,500,1), np.arange(1,501,1), np.arange(2,502,1), np.arange(3,503,1), np.arange(4,504,1), ],
    index=list('abcde'),
     columns=pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range('2011-1-1', periods=500))).transpose()

lists = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5]]) #db_matrix.loc[:, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']].as_matrix()

original_m_numpy_repr = original.loc[:, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']].as_matrix()

for l in lists:
    mask = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.array_equal(x, l), 1, original_m_numpy_repr)
    print(original[mask])
```

have any advice on how to apply it ?

Comment: IIUC you can get the row indices of the matching ones following the answers posted to [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array) and then simply use those row indices to index into the input array/dataframe for the desired o/p.

Comment: *"`np.apply_along_axis` was used to speed the comparison"* `apply_along_axis` is just syntactic sugar - it's unlikely to be faster than a normal Python `for` loop (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23849233/1461210), for example).

Comment: for real? in more than one instance it improved dramatically performance