# Astropy, Numpy: Applying function over coordinates is very slow

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I have a large collection of coordinates contained within a single astropy coordinate object. I would like to apply a function to each coordinate in parallel and produce an output array of the same shape—but this is slow.

*(In my case, the function is a model that takes galactcocentric coordinates and outputs a ‘brightness’ associated with that point in space.)*

Illustration:

```py
In [339]: type(data)
Out[339]: astropy.coordinates.builtin_frames.galactocentric.Galactocentric

In [340]: data.shape, data.size              # Not that big, really
Out[340]: ((21, 21, 31), 13671)

In [341]: data[0,0,0]                        # An example of a single coordinate
Out[341]: 
<Galactocentric Coordinate (galcen_distance=8.3 kpc, galcen_ra=266d24m18.36s, galcen_dec=-28d56m10.23s, z_sun=27.0 pc, roll=0.0 deg): (rho, phi, z) in (kpc, deg, kpc)
    ( 8.29995608,  180.,  0.027)>

In [342]: func = vectorize(lambda coord: 0)  # Dummy function

In [343]: %time func(data).shape
CPU times: user 33.2 s, sys: 88.1 ms, total: 33.3 s
Wall time: 33.4 s
Out[343]: (21, 21, 31)
```

I suspect that this is slow because, at each iteration, a new coordinate object is being initialized before being passed to the vectorized function ([discussion](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/3323)).

A solution might be to convert the coordinate object into a plain numpy array before applying the function, discarding unit information and metadata (since the units are homogenous).

However, I can’t find a way to do that.

---

How should I approach this? If converting to vanilla numpy data types is the best solution, how is that accomplished?

Thanks!

---

Minimal working example:

```
from numpy import *
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import Galactocentric

# Generate lots of coordinates
x = linspace(0, 1, 1e3)*u.pc
data = Galactocentric(x=x, y=0*u.pc, z=0*u.pc)

@vectorize
def func(coord):
    '''ultimately in terms of coord.x, coord.y, coord.z...'''
    return 0

# timeit
func(data)
```

Comment: I usually drop units via `data.si.value`.

Comment: In my case, `data.data` (whoops—unfortunate naming) is a dimensionless `<CartesianRepresentation … >` object, which is in a different coordinate system. My `data` object has `(rho, phi, z)` coordinates, which is what my model requires.

Comment: In I like to use `%timeit`.  `np.vectorize` does not produce fast compiled code; read its speed disclaimer.  Without information about your function we can't help.

Comment: The problem is not with my function. Even the simple example with a function which returns zero is still slow. The problem is with how I iterate the coordinates. Iterating a normal numpy array with my complex function is indeed very fast.

Comment: See https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/3323 for some long-standing discussion of this issue.  It is recognized that this is a real problem, related to initializing coordinate objects.  Perhaps the `fastiter()` solution would work for you, so upvote that on github if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

One solution (but not the best—see edit) is to convert the astropy coordinates to a numpy array, and to then proceed as normal with numpy. This conversion can be done by **extracting each coordinate component separately**:

```
coords_np = stack([coords.rho, coords.phi, coords.z]).value
```

(Since the resulting array would have mixed units, we discard units by taking `.value`.)

Now, coordinate triplets `(rho, phi, z)` are along a new axis,

```
>>> coords_np[:,0,0,0]
array([  <rho>,  <phi>,    <z>])
```

and you may apply your function `(rho, phi, z) -> x` to `coords_np` like so:

```
scalar_field = apply_along_axis(func, 0, coords_np)
```

This result is equivalent performing `func(coords)` (directly on astropy coordinates), but is faster.

---

**Edit:** If possible, avoid `apply_along_axis` altogether by vectorizing the function, instead of applying it to each coordinate. For example, if the function is something like `lambda rho, phi, z: rho**2 + z**2`, then it is *much* faster to simply compute `coords.rho**2 + coords.z**2` than it is to iterate that function over `stack([coords.rho, coords.phi, coords.z])` as above. This has the added advantage of preserving units.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23849233/1937384).