# Evaluate array valued function python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I need to integrate a matrix function as in the example below:

```
def func(a1, a2, a3):
     return np.array([a1, (a1 + a2), a3])
```

The non-efficient way to do this is using three for loops. Although, I would like to make it more efficient. I thought about using "map", like:

```
def integral(func, a1, a2, a3, w):
    f = np.array(list(map(func, a1, a2, a3)))
    I = np.zeros((3, ))
    for fi, wi in zip(f, w):
        I = I + wi*np.array(fi)
    return I
```

`a1`, `a2`, `a3` and `w` are arrays of the same size (a's are the sample points and w are the weights)

Is this the most optimized way to do so?

Comment: If you are going to `zip` `f` there's no point in starting with array.  `zip` on a list is faster.  But the `zip` loop is just `np.dot(w, f)`.

Answer (score 1):

For this function in particular you can vectorize everything.

```
I = w@np.vstack([a1,a1+a2,a3]).T
```

However, in general it [isn't fast to apply a python function over a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849097/numpy-np-apply-along-axis-function-speed-up).

Comment: Ok, but that function in particular was just an example. The real function is far more complicated and has NxM dimension.