# Improving speed of the code when using numpy.apply_along_axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function which takes a two element array as input. Now I have large data (shape = (360000,2)) and want to evaluate the function at each point by using numpy.apply_along_axis . One of the answers given in the this thread([numpy np.apply_along_axis function speed up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849097/numpy-np-apply-along-axis-function-speed-up)) says that numpy.apply_along_axis is not for speed. My function is vectorised. How can I improve the evolution time for all my data without using jit/cython.

I will include a sample code of what I'm trying to do exaclty

```py
import numpy as np
import random
def sample(x):
    return np.sin(x[0])*np.cos(x[1])
data = np.random.normal(size=600*600*2)
data = data.reshape(600*600,2)
%timeit np.sum(np.apply_along_axis(sample, 1,data)) #using the apply_along_axis

def loop_way():  # using loop
    result = []
    for i in data:
        result += [sample(i)]
    return np.sum(result)
%timeit loop_way()


output when using np. apply_along_axis: 1 loop, best of 3: 4.06 s per loop

output for loop_way function: 1 loop, best of 3: 2.41 s per loop
```

Comment: With 3 or more dimensions, `apply_along_axis` is a convenience, easier to write than a double nested loop over the other dimensions.  But with only one loop that doesn't matter.  Your `loop_way` is missing a step, if you want a fair comparison, a `np.array(result)` conversion.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah. I corrected the function.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.sin` and `*` are vectorized operations, so, you can apply them over whole arrays:

```
np.sin(data[:, 0]) * np.cos(data[:, 1])
```

`data[:, 0]` is the first column and `data[:, 1]` is the second.

Note that this should go really fast :)

---

Here is a notebook that tests the speed of each method: [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RFzRZLmQ64JYboCLvpZl9xFmITyyZBTU).

Average run time:

- Method 1 (using `numpy.apply_along_axis`): 2.08s
- Method 2 (loop applying function to rows): 1.14s
- Method 3 (this answer): 17.3ms

Comment: Sorry in method-1 I'm summing all the elements in the array which is yielding a different answer. Now made an edit

Comment: Aaaah, that was it! I really shouldn't be answering questions this close to sleep