# Finding unique values in each row

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array with strings of size of 2 and want to get unique strings in each row.

```
np.__version__
# '1.19.2'
arr = np.array([['Z7', 'Q4', 'Q4'], # 2 unique strings
                ['Q4', 'Z7', 'Q4'], # 2 unq strings
                ['Q4', 'Z7', 'Z7'], # 2 unq strings
                ['Z7', 'Z7', 'Q4'], # 2 unq strings
                ['D8', 'D8', 'L1'], # 2 unq strings
                ['L1', 'L1', 'D8']], dtype='<U2') # 2 unq strings
```

It is guaranteed that every row contains the same number of uniques strings i.e. every row will have the same number of unique strings in my case it's 2.

**Expected output**:

```
array([['Q4', 'Z7'],
       ['Q4', 'Z7'],
       ['Q4', 'Z7'],
       ['Q4', 'Z7'],
       ['D8', 'L1'],
       ['D8', 'L1']], dtype='<U2')
```

Here, each row is sorted but it's doesn't have to be. It's fine both ways.

#### My code:

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.unique, 1, arr)

# array([['Q4', 'Z7'],
#        ['Q4', 'Z7'],
#        ['Q4', 'Z7'],
#        ['Q4', 'Z7'],
#        ['D8', 'L1'],
#        ['D8', 'L1']], dtype='<U2')
```

I thought `np.unique` over axis 1 would give expected results but

```
np.unique(arr, axis=1)
# array([['Q4', 'Q4', 'Z7'],
#        ['Q4', 'Z7', 'Q4'],
#        ['Z7', 'Z7', 'Q4'],
#        ['Q4', 'Z7', 'Z7'],
#        ['L1', 'D8', 'D8'],
#        ['D8', 'L1', 'L1']], dtype='<U2')
```

I couldn't understand what exactly happened and why it returned this exact output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation of *np.unique*, in the description of *axis* parameter,
contains the following statement:

*... subarrays indexed by the given axis will be be flattened treated as the elements of a 1-D array*

So if you call np.unique, passing *axis=1*, then:

- Each **column** is flattened (as each column contains "atomic"
  values, nothing happens).
- Finding of unique elements is performed on the resulting list
  (list of columns). If 2 columns were just the same then only
  one of them would have been retained.
- The result is presented possibly in a changed order (this is
  an internal implementation detail.

A bit of explanation why each **column** (not **row**): Axis "1" is actually "columns".

To confirm that in this case each **column** is the processe object,
define the source array as:

```
arr_2 = np.array([['Z7', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4'],
                  ['Q4', 'Z7', 'Q4', 'Q4'],
                  ['Q4', 'Z7', 'Z7', 'Z7'],
                  ['Z7', 'Z7', 'Q4', 'Q4'],
                  ['D8', 'D8', 'L1', 'L1'],
                  ['L1', 'L1', 'D8', 'D8']])
```

where 2 last columns are just the same.

When you execute `np.unique(arr_2, axis=1)`, the result will
be just the same. Two last **columns** were exactly the same,
so one of them has been eliminated.

Comment: Your explanation hit home for me. Thank you. Is there any better way than `np.apply_along_axis`?

Comment: I think, there is no better approach than *apply_along_axis*.

Answer (score 2):

That is because numpy.unique flattens either the row or column subarrays and then returns the unique rows (axis = 0) or columns (axis = 1), instead of the unique values itself. Take a look at this example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4]])
np.unique(a, axis=0)
```

The output is:

```
array([[1, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4]])
```

and

```
b = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [2, 2, 4]])
np.unique(b, axis=1)
```

The output is:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [4, 2]])
```

In your case you want the unique values per row itself and therefore should apply the along_axis command like you already implemented. The axis = 1 does not do much as your columns are all unique and only shows some sorting.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can make sense of the output given by `np.unique(arr, axis=1)`, Is there any better way than `np.apply_along_axis`?

Comment: I don't really know why you'd want a different solution as this works really well?

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis` is slow it's just a `for-loop` under the hood, not vectorized. [`More details here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849097/numpy-np-apply-along-axis-function-speed-up)