# Use information of two arrays to create a third one

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy-arrays and want to create a third one with the information in these twos.
Here is a simple example:

```
have = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
use = np.array([[2], [3]]) 

solution = np.array([[1, 1, 3, 4], [5, 5, 5, 8]])
```

What I want is to use the "use"-array, which gives me the number of how often I want to use the first element in each row from my "have"-array.
So the 2 in "use" means, that I want to have two times a "1" in my new array "solution". Similary for the "3" in use, I want that my new array has 3 times a "5". The rest from have should be the same.
It is important to use the "use"-array for doing this (or a numpy-array in general).

Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If there are only small such data structures and performance is not an issue then you can do this so simple:

```
np.array([ [a[0]]*b[0]+list(a[b[0]:]) for a,b in zip(have,use)])
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance matters, you can use `np.apply_along_axis()`.

```py
import numpy as np

have = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
use = np.array([[2], [3]])


def rep1st(arr):
    rep = arr[0]
    res = np.repeat(arr[1], rep)
    res = np.concatenate([res, arr[rep+1:]])
    return res


solution = np.apply_along_axis(rep1st, 1, np.concatenate([use, have], axis=1))
```

**update:**

As @[hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) said, actually the method using `apply_along_axis` above is not as efficient as I expected. I misunderstood it. Reference: [numpy np.apply_along_axis function speed up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849097/numpy-np-apply-along-axis-function-speed-up).

However, I made some test on current methods:

```py
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit


def rep1st(arr):
    rep = arr[0]
    res = np.repeat(arr[1], rep)
    res = np.concatenate([res, arr[rep + 1:]])
    return res


def test(row, col, run):
    have = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(row, col))
    use = np.random.randint(0, col, size=(row, 1))
    d = locals()
    d.update(globals())
    # method by me
    t1 = timeit("np.apply_along_axis(rep1st, 1, np.concatenate([use, have], axis=1))", number=run, globals=d)
    # method by @quantummind
    t2 = timeit("np.array([[a[0]] * b[0] + list(a[b[0]:]) for a, b in zip(have, use)])", number=run, globals=d)
    # method by @Amit Vikram Singh
    t3 = timeit(
        "np.where(np.repeat(np.arange(have.shape[1])[None, :], have.shape[0], axis=0) < use, have[:, 0:1], have)",
        number=run, globals=d
    )
    print(f"{t1:8.6f}, {t2:8.6f}, {t3:8.6f}")


test(1000, 10, 10)
test(100, 100, 10)
test(10, 1000, 10)

test(1000000, 10, 1)
test(100000, 100, 1)
test(10000, 1000, 1)
test(1000, 10000, 1)
test(100, 100000, 1)
test(10, 1000000, 1)
```

results:

```
0.062488, 0.028484, 0.000408
0.010787, 0.013811, 0.000270
0.001057, 0.009146, 0.000216

6.146863, 3.210017, 0.044232
0.585289, 1.186013, 0.034110
0.091086, 0.961570, 0.026294
0.039448, 0.917052, 0.022553
0.028719, 0.919377, 0.022751
0.035121, 1.027036, 0.025216
```

It shows that the second method proposed by @[Amit Vikram Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7831421/amit-vikram-singh) always works well even when the arrays are huge.

Comment: Have you actually timed this?  In my experience `apply...` is not a performance tool.

Comment: @hpaulj, you are right and thanks for your reply. I have mistaken this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate through the `have` and replace the values based on the `use`.

Use:

```
for i in range(use.shape[0]):
    have[i, :use[i, 0]] = np.repeat(have[i, 0], use[i, 0])
```

---

Using **only numpy** operations:

First create a boolean `mask` of same size as `have`. `mask(i, j)` is `True` if `j < use[i, j]` otherwise it's `False`. So mask is `True` for indices which are to be replaced by first column value. Now use `np.where` to replace.

```
n, m = have.shape
mask = np.repeat(np.arange(m)[None, :], n, axis = 0) < use
have = np.where(mask, have[:, 0:1], have)
```

Output:

```
>>> have
array([[1, 1, 3, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 8]])
```