# Vectorized/efficient section of numpy matrix-entries based on another numpy vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Here is an example of the situation I want to find an efficient solution for:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.array([0,1,2])
```

The vector *b* should have one integer entry for each row of *a*, ranging between 0 and the number of columns of *a*.
The desired output *c* is a matrix in the shape of *a*, with i-th row containing every entry
up to (and excluding) the b[i]-th entry of i-th row of a, the rest of the row should be filled up with zeros. Hence, in the example given, we look for the following solution:

```
c = np.array([[0,0,0],[4,0,0],[7,8,0]])
```

There are two "easy" ways to do this:

```
c = np.zeros(a.shape)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    c[i, :b[i]] =  a[i, :b[i]]
```

another is by first defining an auxiliary matrix and consequently broadcasting it against *a*.

```
aux = np.zeros(a.shape)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    aux[i, :b[i]] = 1 
c = a * aux
```

What I am looking for are *vectorized solutions* that scale well in runtime when I increase the number of *rows* of *a*.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67173501/7831421    . Note that  in this answer `use = b[:, None]` and `have` is your `a`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Using the link, I came up with the following idea:  First
```n, m = a.shape```, then
```aux = np.repeat(np.arange(m)[None,:], n, axis = 0) < b```, and finally
```c = a * aux```. However, my knowledge in python is far too limited to tell whether this is the solution that scales best in runtime when I increase the number of rows.

Comment: Yes. That should do the job if you use `b[:, None]` is place of `b` while creating `aux`.

Comment: @H1ghfiv3 You need to reshape the `b` so it gets broadcasted correctly: `aux = np.repeat(np.arange(m)[None,:], n, axis = 0) < b.reshape(-1, 1)` (try with non-square matrix `a`)

Comment: Right, I mixed up the input shape of b with the (correct) one that I've tested the code with on my pc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy broadcasting to create a boolean `mask` which is `False` for the `indices > b[i]` i.e. indices where `a` should be replaced by `0`. Then multiply `a` with the `mask` to get `c`.

```
n, m = a.shape
mask = np.repeat(np.arange(m)[None, :], n, axis = 0) < b[:, None]
c = mask * a
```

Output:

```
>>> c
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can make a mask matrix and multiply `a` element-wise by that mask:

```
a * (np.mgrid[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]][1] < b.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 0]])
```

Here's step-by-step how the mask is constructed:

```
np.mgrid[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]][1]
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [0, 1, 2],
#        [0, 1, 2]])

np.mgrid[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]][1] < b.reshape(-1, 1)
# array([[False, False, False],
#        [ True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True, False]])
```