# How to apply a function with different arguments on a NumPy 1d-array to make a 2d-array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a NumPy 1d-array `a`:

```py
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

and I have a function `foo`:

```py
def foo(x, p):
    ...
    return y
```

I want to apply `foo` on `a` with, say, `p` from 1 to 3 to make a 2d-array.

Comment: What is the problem with a simple `for` loop?

Comment: I want to avoid `for` loops, due to the computational cost. In fact, my question is the simplified version of my main problem where I have millions of rows and arguments.

Comment: Is the foo function just the power function?

Comment: @DaniMesejo not necessarily.

Comment: I should identify a proper `duplicate` for this kind of question since it comes up so often.  If `foo` can only be called with specific dimensions, e.g. 1d for `x` and scalar for `p`, it has to be called once for each such combination.  Calling that many times is what takes up the time, not the details of the iteration mechanism.  To reduce time in `numpy` you need to use `numpy` compiled methods without iteration, for example `**` power with  (n,) and (1,m) shaped arrays to produce a (n,m) result.  **Learn `numpy` before trying to "avoid loops".**

Comment: Thank you sir @hpaulj definitely I am not a NumPy specialist. This is the very reason I ask here and people are here to help each other and provide useful hints and resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just:

```
>>> a[:, None] ** np.arange(1, 4)
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  4,  8],
       [ 3,  9, 27]], dtype=int32)
>>>
```

With a function:

```
def foo(x, p):
    return x ** p

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: foo(x, np.arange(1, 4)), 1, a[:, None])
```

---

```
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  4,  8],
       [ 3,  9, 27]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks, @U12-Forward but my question is in general. I represent the general question here in a simple fashion just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi Edited my answer with working code with functions

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi - Asking *in general* can lead to wrong assumptions. This solution is correct but can be as [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23849233/14277722) as a `python` loop. Most functions can be vectorized for fast computation with `numpy`.

Comment: This doesn't avoid a loop.  `apply_along_axis` hides the loop, and is actually slower.  It has to perform a trial call just to determine the return value.  Please do not recommend it, especially if the OP wants to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

In you comment you say `you want to give both arguments to function` For this purpose you can use `map` and `functools` like below:

```
from functools import partial

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

def foo(x,y,z):
    return list(z ** y + x)

list(map(partial(foo, z=a), range(1,4), range(1,4)))
```

Output:

```
[
 [3, 4, 5],  # [1,2,3]**1+1
 [3, 6, 11], # [1,2,3]**2+2
 [3, 10, 29] # [1,2,3]**3+3
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually, I have to give both arguments `a` and `p` to my function `foo`. Also, the function is not actually a simple power function, I just put `foo` here like this to simplify the problem,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `numpy` module support math function .So, if you want to apply mathematic function on an array you only have to write it as normal function or a lambda function, then apply it on your array .For example:

```
def foo(x,p):
    return numpy.power(x,p)
```

**Note** : these much more matematical function in the numpy module . Try to take a look on them :) .

Comment: `**` also works...

Comment: Thanks, @Ayyoub but I was looking for a general way to apply a function along an axis.

Comment: Do you mean a line in an ndarray ?