# Python apply_along_axis of multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a function, f(x) which takes a single 1d-array as argument and produces a 1d-array as output, I can use [numpy.apply_along_axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html#numpy.apply_along_axis) to apply the function, to each row of a 2d-array X whose rows are valid arguments for f.

Now I want to do the analogous thing with a function that takes two arguments.
E.g. I have a function f(x, y) which takes tow 1d-arrays as arguments and I also have two 2d-arrays X, Y both with n rows. I want to apply f to each pair of rows, producing an array which has again n rows.

How to accomplish this in an efficient way?

I am also interested in variants, where f takes more arguments or higher dimensional arrays are involved:

For example f could take 3 arrays x, y, z of shape (2,2); (3,); (5,)
and produce a result of shape (4,4).

I have X, Y, Z of shapes (50, 100, 2, 2); (50, 100, 3); (50, 100, 5)
and want a result of shape (50, 100, 4, 4)

Comment: I just had this question and found a nice Q/A on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740021/numpy-apply-function-to-two-numpy-arrays-and-return-two-numpy-arrays) that uses [numpy.frompyfunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) ... FYI in case this is helpful to anyone who lands here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the code for  `numpy.apply_along_axis` I see that it just iterates over the other dimensions, applying your function to each 'row'.  There's extra code that allows for dimensions about 2.  But for 2d `X` it boils down to:

```
result = np.empty_like(X)
for i, x in enumerate(X):
    result[i] = func1d(x)
```

There's also code to deduce what shape the `result` should have.  For example if `func1d` is `np.sum`, then `result` will be 1d, not 2d like the input.

So there's not special 'efficiency' in this function.  An extension to multiple inputs could be a normal Python zip:

```
 result = np.empty_like(X)
 for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(X,Y)):
     result[i] = func1d(x,y)
```

---

`np.ndindex` is handy tool for generating indices.  It's worth looking at its code.   It uses the general purpose numpy iterator, `np.nditer`, which see: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

> For example f could take 3 arrays x, y, z of shape (2,2); (3,); (5,) and produce a result of shape (4,4).
>
> I have X, Y, Z of shapes (50, 100, 2, 2); (50, 100, 3); (50, 100, 5) and want a result of shape (50, 100, 4, 4)

```
for i,j in np.ndindex(50,100):
    result[i,j,:,:] = f(X[i,j,:,:], Y[i,j,:,:], Z[i,j,:,:])
```

The ':' aren't necessary, but make it clear that we are indexing on 2 of the dimensions, and slicing the rest.  They would be required if you wanted to iterate on the 1 and 3rd dimensions, and slice the 2nd.

Comment: wow thanks! I thought always thought apply_along_axis would be more efficient than a for loop.