# Concatenating two string columns of numpy array into single column in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as following :

```
2016-07-02  10:55:01
2016-07-02  10:55:01
2016-07-02  10:55:01
2016-07-02  17:01:34
2016-07-02  17:01:34
2016-07-02  16:59:52
2016-07-02  17:01:34
2016-07-02  16:59:52
2016-07-02  16:59:52
2016-07-02  10:40:00
2016-07-02  12:01:14
```

this are two columns of array. date and time. but i want both into a single column concatenated by '\t'. both the values are in string  format.

I did it by a loop as follows, but that is a bad idea and taking much time. :

```
for D in Data:
    Data2 = np.append(Data2,np.array(D[0]+"\t"+D[1]))
```

Please suggest an efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neat, but not more efficient than simple loop (as Praveen pointed out in comment):

```
import numpy as np


np.apply_along_axis(lambda d: d[0] + '\t' + d[1], 1, arr)
```

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis` _isn't_ a vectorized solution. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28904614/525169) answer... It just internally uses a for loop, so this doesn't really speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

Insert the tabs `\t` into your array using `numpy.insert` and then do a `numpy.reshape` from n by 3 to n*3 by 1

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a=[[1],[2],[3]]
b=[[4],[5],[6]]

np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Below method works for any two or more columns. It is very convenient if you want to concatenate **multiple columns** at a time, or even the **whole row**, because you don't have to explicitly write d[0] + '\t' + d[1] + ...
2. On my computer it performs 50~60% faster than `apply_along_axis()` given above.

To concatenate the whole row delimited by '\t'

```
result = list(['\t'.join(row) for row in data])
```

Or if the actual row is larger and you only want to concatenate the first two columns:

```
result = list(['\t'.join(row[0:2]) for row in data])
```

Performance Comparison of both methods for 10,000 iterations with a very tiny data-set (< 100 rows) :

| Method | Time (ms) |
| --- | --- |
| **Above method** | **350 ms** |
| `apply_along_axis()` | 870 ms |