# Efficient convolution of two images along one axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have two large grayscale images. Either PIL.Image or numpy data structure.

How do I do 1d convolution of the two images along one axis?

The best I come up with is

```
def conv2(im1, im2, *args):
    res = 0
    for l1, l2 in zip(im1, im2):
        res += np.convolve(l1, l2, *args)
    return res
```

Which works, but not extremely fast. Is there a faster way?

Please note that all the 2D convolution functions are probably not relevant since I am not interested in a 2D convolution. I've seen this question on SO before, but I didn't see a better answer than my code. So I'm bumping it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convolution along one axis only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228718/convolution-along-one-axis-only)

Answer (score 2):

FFT along one axis, multiply along one axis and inverse FFT.
Should be MUCH faster according to [this explanation](http://www.dspguide.com/ch18/2.htm)
Scipy.signal.fftconvolve should do the job.