# Numpy Methods to improve my Moving Average function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function to calculate the moving average of numpy arrays imported from a file. This function works fine, but I was wondering if anyone knows a quicker method, using one of numpy methods to have the same outcome??

Data:

```
b = [[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [4, 5, 6]]

def mod_movAvg(arr):
    rowNum, colNum = arr.shape
    res = np.zeros((rowNum - 1, colNum))
    for col in range(colNum):
        for row in range(rowNum - 1):
            res[row][col] = 0.5*(arr[row][col] + arr[row+1][col])
    return res
```

output:

```
[[1.5 2.5 3.5]
 [2.5 3.5 4.5]
 [4.5 5.5 6.5]
 [5.  6.  7. ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `b` can be converted to a numpy matrix (which are stored more efficiently in memory) using:

```py
b = np.matrix(b)
```

Then, you can just do what you want more efficiently using:

```py
result = 0.5 * (b[:-1,:] + b[1:,:])
```

`result` will be a numpy matrix too.

Answer (score 1):

`Convolution` is the keyword here. You have a 2D array but perform the convolution only along one axis, so maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228718/convolution-along-one-axis-only) is relevant.

- for 1D convolution you could use `numpy.convolve()`
- for 2D convolution  you could use `scipy.signal.covolve2d()`

In you case you move the kernel with shape `(2,1)`

`[[0.5],[0.5]]`

over the array to get the values

`res[row][col] = 0.5*arr[row][col] + 0.5*arr[row+1][col]`

Applied to your example:

```
import scipy.signal as sg

b = [[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 4],
     [3, 4, 5],
     [6, 7, 8],
     [4, 5, 6]]

res = sg.convolve2d(b, [[0.5], [0.5]], mode='valid')
```

This approach is fast and easy to generalize:

```py
kernel = (3, 2)
sg.convolve2d(arr, np.full(kernel, 1/np.size(kernel)), mode='valid')
```